# nested forloop with if else statement php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-3

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6AMo.png)

```css
my controller
public function admin() {
        $data['employee'] = $this->attendance_model->get_attendance();
        // get today's all employee attendance details
        $data['attendance'] = $this->attendance_model->attendance();
        // attendance page
        $data['header'] = "Employee";
        $data['sub_header'] = "Attendance employee";
        $data['main_content'] = 'attendance/admin_list';
        $this->load->view('employeelayout/main',$data);
    }

my model
// get the employee details
    public  function get_attendance () {
        return $this->db->get('employee')->result();
    }
    
    public function attendance() {
        $today = date('Y-m-d');  // get today date
        $this->db->where('A.date',$today)->from('attendance A')
        ->join('employee E','E.employee_id = A.employee_id','LEFT');
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

```html
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>             
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Employee Number</th>
                     <th>Today</th>
                    <th>Mark Incoming</th>       
                    <th class="hidden-phone">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
           
            <tbody>
                <?php $count = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach($employee as $emp) {  ?>
                 
               <tr class="gradeX">
                    <td><?php echo $count ++ ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $emp->first_name.' '.$emp->last_name ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $emp->employee_number ?></td>
                    <?php foreach($attendance as $atten) {  ?>
                    
                    <?php if($emp->employee_id == $atten->employee_id) { ?> 
                    <td><?php echo $atten->date ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $atten->mark_in_time ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "present" ?></td>
                    <?php } else {  ?>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?php echo "absent" ?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
               </tr> 
               
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
```

i used nested foreach ,
1st I display the all employee in first foreach
2nd i want to display the employee attendance with present and absent 
from attendance table I match employee_id with employee table of employee_id
where it display the all present employee and it properly displaying the absent. any help please

i posted the image, you can see, i display all the employees, i'm checking if employee-id = employee-id (means exist in the attendance table). if exists display "present" else "absent". but it over looping.

Comment: Whats the issue again?

Comment: i have employee table and daily attendance table. I want display the today attendance, like who r absent & present. you can see  the controller and model. I posted above. I want to display the all the employees with today's absent and present.

Comment: why u used 2 functions?

Comment: that is my model , getting value from 2 tables

Comment: First pass the employeeid to attendance() function.  and change your queries with A.employee_id =$employeeid. Then you got particular employee with present or abssent detail.(Having 1 result only). then display it

Comment: i don't need specific employee . I want all employee with absent and present. i add the image . please check it

Comment: from your advice i get the specific employees only , i want all who r absent too

Comment: query itself you have take present absent result properly. dnt go nested loop. Can u provide table columns name.

Comment: brother, if employee_id exists in both the table that mean it's present else absent . instead of displaying the value i display the value. no problem with that. i attached the image please check out

Comment: my kind advice, pls avoid looping. In your result, taking long time to show result. because each employee id check all records of attendance table. If 10000 records in attendance means, your page execution takes long time.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT e.*, CASE WHEN (a.attendance_id is null) THEN 'absent' ELSE 'present' END as presentinfo FROM `employee` e left join attendance a on e.employee_id=a.employee_id and a.date=date(now())
```

Your Html Page look like:

```
           <tr class="gradeX">
                <td><?php echo $emp->first_name.' '.$emp->last_name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $emp->employee_number ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $emp->presentinfo ?></td>
           </tr> 

            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
```

My suggestion : Use above query.. It will display your needed result.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

your model

```
public  function get_attendance () {

    $arrEmployee = $this->db->get('employee')->result();

    $arrEmployeeById = array();
    $arrEmployeeIds = array();
    foreach($arrEmployee AS $objEmployee)
    {
        $objEmployee->arrAttendance = array();
        $arrEmployeeById[$objEmployee->employee_id] = $objEmployee;
        $arrEmployeeIds[] = $objEmployee->employee_id;
    }

    $this->db->where_in("A.employee_id",$arrEmployeeIds);
    $arrAttendances = $this->attendance();

    foreach($arrAttendances AS $objAttendence)
    {
        if (isset($arrEmployeeById[$objAttendence->employee_id]))   $arrEmployeeById[$objAttendence->employee_id]->arrAttendance[] = $objAttendence;
    }

    return $arrEmployee;

    //return $this->db->get('employee')->result();
}

public function attendance() 
{
    $today = date('Y-m-d');  // get today date
    $this->db->where('A.date',$today)->from('attendance A')
    //->join('employee E','E.employee_id = A.employee_id','LEFT');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

your controller

```
public function admin() {
    $data['employee'] = $this->attendance_model->get_attendance();
    $data['header'] = "Employee";
    $data['sub_header'] = "Attendance employee";
    $data['main_content'] = 'attendance/admin_list';
    $this->load->view('employeelayout/main',$data);
}
```

//your view

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>             
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Employee Number</th>
         <th>Today</th>
        <th>Mark Incoming</th>       
        <th class="hidden-phone">Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php $count = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach($employee as $emp) {  ?>

   <tr class="gradeX">
        <td><?php echo $count ++ ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $emp->first_name.' '.$emp->last_name ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $emp->employee_number ?></td>
        <?php 
        if (count($emp->arrAttendance) > 0)
        {
            foreach($emp->arrAttendance as $atten) {  
        ?>
                <td><?php echo $atten->date ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $atten->mark_in_time ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "present" ?></td>
        <?php
            }
        }
        else 
        {  
        ?>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo "absent" ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
   </tr> 
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```